# To Print GunZip File Name with Output:

Tags: awk

Would like to print  file name along with file located in the directory (pwd), All are *.gz extension files.
For example `Master.csv.gz` located at `/cygdrive/e/Test/Master.csv.gz` and 
Input files are located in different sub directories like `/cygdrive/f/Jan/Input_Jan.csv.gz` & `/cygdrive/f/Feb/Input_Feb.csv.gz`  and so on ..

Below command is working fine without file name directory:

```
awk ' BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} FNR==NR {a[$2] = $0; next} ($2 in a) {print $0}'  <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/e/Test/Master.csv.gz) <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/f/Jan/Input_Jan.csv.gz)
awk ' BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} FNR==NR {a[$2] = $0; next} ($2 in a) {print $0}'  <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/e/Test/Master.csv.gz) <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/f/Feb/Input_Feb.csv.gz)
```

Output:

```
Name,Age,Location
abc,20,xxx
def,40,yyy
```

Have tried below command to print file name directory and in- complete

```
awk ' BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} FNR==NR {a[$2] = $0; next} ($2 in a) {print $0,FILENAME}'  <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/e/Test/Master.csv.gz) <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/f/Jan/Input_Jan.csv.gz)
awk ' BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} FNR==NR {a[$2] = $0; next} ($2 in a) {print $0,FILENAME}'  <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/e/Test/Master.csv.gz) <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/f/Feb/Input_Feb.csv.gz)

awk ' BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} FNR==NR {a[$2] = $0; next} ($2 in a) {print $0,$file}'  <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/e/Test/Master.csv.gz) <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/f/Jan/Input_Jan.csv.gz)
awk ' BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} FNR==NR {a[$2] = $0; next} ($2 in a) {print $0,$file}'  <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/e/Test/Master.csv.gz) <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/f/Feb/Input_Feb.csv.gz)
```

Desired Output:

```
Name,Age,Location, FileName1,FileName2
abc,20,xxx,/cygdrive/e/Test/Master.csv.gz,/cygdrive/f/Jan/Input_Jan.csv.gz
def,40,yyy,/cygdrive/e/Test/Master.csv.gz,/cygdrive/f/Feb/Input_Feb.csv.gz
```

Looking for your suggestions ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that awk doesn't see your input files. It sees the process substitution files. So you can't get the name you want from there.

Something like this should work though (at the cost of repeating yourself).

```
awk ' BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} FNR==NR {a[$2] = $0; next} ($2 in a) {print $0,$file}' file=/cygdrive/e/Test/Master.csv.gz <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/e/Test/Master.csv.gz) file=/cygdrive/f/Jan/Input_Jan.csv.gz <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/f/Jan/Input_Jan.csv.gz)
```

You might be able to play games with passing just the filenames to awk and then using `getline` from a piped command to do this also but I don't think that's worth it.